# Java: Call Perl script with Process(): wsd.pl

Tags: java, perl, word-sense-disambiguation

I got the terminal to work with SenseRelate::AllWords, with this command:

```
wsd.pl --context test.txt --format raw --
```

However, now I'm trying to run wsd.pl from my Java code, it looks like this:

```
public static void main(String args[] ) throws IOException {
        String line;
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("wsd.pl", "--context test.txt", "--format raw");
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        Process process =  pb.start();
        InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream();


        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(stdout));

        while ((line = reader.readLine ()) != null) {
            System.out.println ("Stdout: " + line);
        }
    }
```

It gives me errors:

```
Stdout: Unknown option: context test.txt
Stdout: Unknown option: format raw
```

test.txt path is to the source folder of the project (top level, next to src, .git, etc.)

I've tried some different ways: adding arguments to a list and create a new process based on that list, different ways of formatting the arguments but no, it won't work. Can someone help out? I guess it's some syntax I'm not familiar with.

Thanks!

Comment: My first thought would be to make sure your working directory is what you actually think it is.  My second thought would be to check your perl script as it seems like it's giving you valid output, and this may not be an issue of calling from java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("wsd.pl", "--context", "test.txt", "--format", "raw");
```

Also make sure your working directory is correct.